# Composite unique constraint on business fields with Axon

Tags: cqrs, axon, eventual-consistency

We leverage AxonIQ Framework in our system. We've faced a problem implementing composite uniq constraint based on aggregate business fields.

Consider following Aggregate:

```
@Aggregate
public class PersonnelCardAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private UUID personnelCardId;

    private String personnelNumber;

    private Boolean archived;

}
```

We want to avoid personnelNumber duplicates in the scope of NOT-archived (archived == false) records. At the same time personnelNumber duplicates may exist in the scope of archived records.

Query Side check seems NOT to be an option. Taking into account Eventual Consistency nature of our system, more than one creation request with the same personnelNumber may exist at the same time and the Query Side may be behind.

What the solution would be?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is an issue that can occur as soon as you start implementing an application along the CQRS paradigm and DDD modeling techniques.

The `PersonnelCardAggregate` in your scenario maintains the consistency boundary of a single "Personnel Card". You are however looking to expand this scope to achieve a uniqueness constraints among all Personnel Cards in your system.

I feel that this blog explains the problem of "[Set Based Consistency Validation](http://danielwhittaker.me/2017/10/09/handle-set-based-consistency-validation-cqrs/)" you are encountering quite nicely.
I will not iterate his entire blog, but he sums it up as having four options to resolving the problem:

1. Introduce locking, transactions and database constraints for your Personnel Card
2. Use a hybrid locking field prior to issuing your command
3. Really on the eventually consistent Query Model
4. Re-examine the domain model

To be fair, option 1 wont do if your using the Event-Driven approach to updating your Command and Query Model.
Option 3 has been pushed back by you in the original question.

Option 4 is something I cannot deduce for you given that I am not a domain expert, but I am guessing that the `PersonnelCardAggregate` does not belong to a larger encapsulating Aggregate Root. Maybe the business constraint you've stated, thus the option to reuse `personalNumbers`, could be dropped or adjusted? Like I said though, I cannot state this as a factual answer for you, as I am not the domain expert.

That leaves option 2, which in my eyes would be the most pragmatic approach too.
I feel this would require a combination of a cache at your command dispatching side to deal with quick successions of commands to resolve the eventual consistency issue. To capture the occurs that an update still comes through accidentally, I'd introduce some form of Event Handler that (1) knows the entire set of "PersonnelCards" from a `personalNumber`/`archived` point of view and (2) can react on a faulty introduction by dispatching a compensating action.

You'd thus introduce some business logic on the event handling side of your application, which I'd strongly recommend to segregate from the application part which updates your query models (as the use cases are entirely different).

Concluding though, this is a difficult topic with several ways around it. 
It's not so much an Axon specific problem by the way, but more an occurrence of modeling your application through DDD and CQRS.